# Reading file to class object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, loops, fstream

I am having trouble reading a file to my class object's members. It says it cannot read the file.

This is my class:

```
const int SIZE_OF = 5;

class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    Student(const Student &);
    Student(string, int, int, int, int, int);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S);
    void display();
private:
    string lastName;
    int grades[SIZE_OF];
};
```

The cpp file associated with my class object to define the functions:

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
    int i;
    string lastName = "default";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = 0;
    }

}

Student::Student(const Student & S)
{
    int i;
    lastName = S.lastName;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = S.grades[i];
    }
}

Student::Student(string S, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    lastName = S;
    grades[0] = a;
    grades[1] = b;
    grades[2] = c;
    grades[3] = d;
    grades[4] = e;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S)
{
    char dummy;
    in >> S.lastName >> S.grades[0]
        >> dummy >> S.grades[1]
        >> dummy >> S.grades[2]
        >> dummy >> S.grades[3]
        >> dummy >> S.grades[4];
    return in;

}

void Student::display()
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    cout << "Last Name: " << lastName << endl;
    cout << "Grades: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << grades[i] << endl;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[i];
    }
    average = sum / 5;
    cout << "Average: " << average;

}
```

And finally, the main function that I have so far to test the file opening and reading it to the various variables inside the class.

```
void main()
{
    fstream     File;
    string      FileName = "ProgramSixData.txt";
    bool        FoundFile;
    string      Line;
    Student     testStudent;

    do {
        File.open(FileName, ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
        FoundFile = File.is_open();
        if (!FoundFile)
        {
            cout << "Could not open file named " << FileName << endl;
            File.open(FileName, ios_base::out); // try to create it
            FoundFile = File.is_open();
            if (!FoundFile)
            {
                cout << "Could not create file named " << FileName << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            else;
        }
        else;
    } while (!FoundFile);
    do {
        File >> testStudent;
        if (File.fail())
        {
            cout << "Read Failed" << endl;
            cout << "Bye" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else;
        testStudent.display();
    } while (!File.eof());
    cout << "Bye" << endl;
    File.close();
}
```

The text document that I am reading from is the following:

```
George
75,85,95,100,44
Peter
100,100,100,100,100
Frank
44,55,66,77,88
Alfred
99,88,77,66,55
```

How do I save each of the names and the associated 5 grades to a particular object of the student class?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: What is not working out exactly? Also an if statement does not necessarily need an else..

Comment: In my main statement I have it read out "read failed" if it encounters File.fail() and that is what is happening.

Comment: @TejaS _`while (!File.eof());`_ [looks wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: The issue is that my file is not being read into the class object's variables. There may be something written wrong?

Comment: When you write code, start with something simple that works perfectly, then build up slowly. Try reading a file of `int` before you attempt a file of `Student`.

Comment: Seems no special issue with the program, and I could run it on my machine.  The issue may be that the file does not exist in the working directory, you may specify FileName as "d:\\ProgramSixData.txt" and put the data in d:\ to try again. And also the first File.open is intended for only read, so you could remove the ios::out. Change do-while to while as suggested by  πάντα ῥεῖ is also right, to handle empty file case.

Answer (score 0):

You are digging too deep. I made an example solution for you, focusing on the parsing. Things could be way shorter and we could instantly make the students instead of doing it the map way, but I want you to understand how to parse the file, because that is obviously what you are struggling with. Ask me anything about the code if you don't understand it.

```
void main()
{
    string      FileName = "ProgramSixData.txt";
    bool        FoundFile;
    string      Line;
    vector<Student> Students;

    ifstream file(FileName); //an ifstream is an INPUTstream (same as a fstream with ::in flag. Passing the FileName as argument opens that file
    if (file.fail()) //check if the file opened correctly
    {
        cout << "Failed to open inputfile\n";
        return;
    }

    map <string, vector<int>> studentAndGrades; //map is a container that uses keys and values, every key has a value, we will use the name of the student as the key to access his marks (a vector of int)
    vector<string> allLines;
    string line;
    while (file >> line) //these 2 linessimply reads ALL the lines to the allLines vector
        allLines.push_back(line);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < allLines.size(); i += 2) //loop over all lines, by 2 at a time (1 for the students name and 1 for his marks)
    {
        vector<int> numbers;

        size_t lastCommaIdx = 0;
        size_t currentCount = 0;
        string scores(allLines[i + 1]); //make a copy of allLines[i + 1] for convenient use
        bool firstLine = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < scores.size(); ++i) //following code is just to split the numbers from the comma's and put them in a vector of int
        {
            if (scores[i] == ',')
            {
                if (firstLine)
                {
                    numbers.push_back(stoi(scores.substr(lastCommaIdx, currentCount)));
                    firstLine = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    numbers.push_back(stoi(scores.substr(lastCommaIdx + 1, currentCount)));
                }
                lastCommaIdx = i;
                currentCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ++currentCount;
            }
        }
        numbers.push_back(stoi(scores.substr(lastCommaIdx + 1))); //last number
        studentAndGrades.insert(make_pair(allLines[i], numbers)); //finally, insert them in the map
    }

    for (const auto& student : studentAndGrades)
        Students.push_back(Student(student.first, student.second[0], student.second[1], student.second[2], student.second[3], student.second[4])); //make students from the information that we read into the map

    for (auto& student : Students) //display all students with a range based for loop
        student.display();
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting indentifier map is undefined? Sorry I'm a beginner at C++ so I don't know how that works.

Comment: I added the map header file but the stuff written there is all way over my head. I just need a basic method of reading from the file which my file which is not doing even though my file is opening.

Comment: @TejaS Allright, let me add some explanation for you then :)

Comment: @TejaS I added a lot of explanation, try to understand everything and if you get stuck, just ask.